# Selecting a computer for the OFFLINE Electrum Wallet

Tags: wallet, electrum, offline

Would a Samsung Chromebook be a suitable choice to run the offline wallet???
I read that Chromebooks run a Unix based OS.
(I would obviously disable networking, bluetooth etc.)

Thanks

Comment: May I suggest a hardware wallet instead? [Hardware Wallets](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Hardware_wallet). More specifically the Pi-wallet.

Answer (score 2):

It seems possible but a bit of a hassle to install python (required for Electrum).

According to this
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299685/programming-on-samsung-chromebook)
you can enable [Developer Mode](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/samsung-series-5-chromebook) to get a shell.

Alternatively there seems to be a [Chrome plugin to get a shell](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo).

Thus, if you already have the Chromebook it is a viable choice. Otherwise I would suggest a cheap system which allows more freedom out of the box.